# How to Calculate Percentage of Total in Dataframe Column Stacked on Top of Total of Column (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so let's say I have a dataframe:

```
data = [['1', 10,], ['2', 15], ['3', 14]] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id', '# of Wagons'])
```

The output looks like:

```
  id  # of Wagons
0  1           10
1  2           15
2  3           14
```

How do I create percentages of the total while also keeping the total? If I use the .apply() function, I apply percentages to every value in the column, including the total, which I want to avoid doing.
My preferred output is:

```
       id  # of Wagons  new_column
0       1           10  25.64%
1       2           15  38.46%
2       3           14  35.89%
Total                     39
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.Series.div` then use `{:.precision%}.format` to get values as percentage values.

```
df.assign(new_col = df['# of Wagons'].div(df['# of Wagons'].sum()).map('{:.2%}'.format))
  id  # of Wagons new_col
0  1           10  25.64%
1  2           15  38.46%
2  3           14  35.90%
```

**Note:**

- `'{:.precision%}'` is part of python's [`mini string language`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df['New']=df['# of Wagons']/df['# of Wagons'].sum()
df=df.append(pd.Series(['Total',df['# of Wagons'].sum(),1],index=df.columns),ignore_index=True)
df
Out[158]: 
      id  # of Wagons       New
0      1           10  0.256410
1      2           15  0.384615
2      3           14  0.358974
3  Total           39  1.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the percentage based on the '# of Wagons' like so:

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 from pandas import DataFrame   
 total = np.sum(df.loc[:,'# of Wagons':].values)
 df['percent'] = df.loc[:,'# of Wagons':].sum(axis=1)/total * 100
 df
```

And if you want to add a 'Total' row you can use this:

```
df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
total = sum(df['# of Wagons'].values)
df["percentage"] = df['# of Wagons'].apply(lambda x: "{:.2f}%".format((x/total)*100))
print(df)
#  id  # of Wagons percentage
#0  1           10     25.64%
#1  2           15     38.46%
#2  3           14     35.90%
```